# Postman missing Status Description

Tags: rest, postman, http-status

I just took the latest update from Postman and now it doesn't display the Status Description when my service returns.  To give a little background, my REST service returns specific messages back with a 400 error and the older version of Postman used to display those.  Now I just see "400 Bad Request."  Any idea of where I can find that information? I know how to get there from enabling the console and watching the network traffic, I'm just looking for it to be user friendly like it user to be.

Answer (score 0):

PostMan has a new update and the Status Description is now available